# Proper method for a hashmap and array calculation using a csv. file for the data

Tags: java, csv, for-loop, while-loop, logic

I have a project that requires me to search though a list given a name time and status, and write a loop that loop that initializes at 0 and begins to count the number of occurrences when the number variable changes from X to Y.

For example take 2 apps with the given data

```
application:xyz time(min):0 status:200 
application:abc time(min):0 status:404
application:xyz time(min):1 status:404
application:abc time(min):1 status:200
application:xyz time(min):2 status:404
application:abc time(min):2 status:404
```

the calculation would go like Looking at XYZ, it starts out in 200 but changes to 404( which we will call N). ABC transitions to 200 in minute 1, transitions to 404 in minute 2. both have a total runtime of 2 minutes (S).
So for both XYZ and ABC we get

```
N=1 and S=2 and Ans=S/N =2 minutes
```

I cant seem to wrap my head around the logic because i am supposed to be getting the data from a read csv. and then do this calculation. Any tips on the method?